# Reg. US Vistor Visa (B2)

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I already have B1 Visa processed through my organization. I am applying for B2 (Visitor visa) for self (me).. Please let me know if i need to fill a separate DS160 for the same ? thanks

Comment: Are you completely sure the visa that you already have is a "B-1" visa and not a "B-1/B-2" visa? The pure B-1 visas are rare.

Comment: Have you already received the B-1 visa? If not you can ask for a B-1/B-2 during your interview without paying another fee.